# Why a variable of type interface holding class object reference is not calling a class member function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, c#-4.0, interface

Why a varaible of type interface holding class object's reference is not calling a class member function?

```
Public Interface IPerson 
{   
    void SetAge(int age);
}
Public class Man : IPerson
{
    Public void SetAge(int age ){}
    Public int GetAge(){return 20 ;}
}
Iperson p = new Man();
```

why p is not calling GetAge()?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? The code you posted is not even valid c#.

Comment: Its not clear from your question but I think you are asking why you can't call GetAge on your p variable... because IPerosn does not have a GetAge method

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are creating the object of `Man` with the reference of `IPerson` and `GetAge()` method does not belong to `IPerson` interface.

As per rule of inheritance methods present **only** in child class cannot be accessed via the reference of parent.

Comment: but it's a shallow copy means now both are pointing to same memory location. So, why don't it?

Comment: Yeah but the reference is of IPerson and it does not have access to methods solely belonging to Man class. It is due to dynamic polymorphism that IPerson can refer to the object of Man class, but privacy rule prohibit it to access methods solely available in Man class

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to provide where you **call** `GetAge`. But anyway the actual type `Man` is a **runtime-information**, which isn´t available to the compiler. Imagine you´d get an instance of `IPerson` from a web-service

```
IPerson p = service.GetPerson();
```

How should the **compiler** know that this instance is actually a `Man` or whatever? Imagine further there´s another class that implements your interface. You 
 see the problem? The compiler can´t know which class the service returns **at runtime**. This is why you can´t access members that are specific to the implementing classes. There simply is not member `GetAge` on `IPerson`. In fact any base-class or -interface should *never* know anything of its child-classes.

If you know the exact type at **compile**-time you can of course either cast to that specific type or just define your variable as of this type:

```
Man p = new Man();
```